# Azure Maps Indoor Module: Change floor without user input

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I've been working with the Azure maps indoor module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps . You can allow a user to pick a level with a level control element from the library, however I cannot figure out a way to pre-set a certain level (e.g. I want to start with a certain facility and the 2nd level pre selected when the map loads.) For the facility there is a indoorManager.setFacility() function that allows you to select a facility but I have not found the equivalent for the level.

**Requirement**: I want to to select a level in Azure Maps without user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any official way to do this yet, note that Azure Maps Creator is still in preview. That said, I did figure out a hacky way around this (may break in the future).

```
var facilityId = 'FCL13';
var level = 2;

//Set the facility and the levels "ordinal number". The ordinal number appears to be off by 1.
indoorManager.setFacility(facilityId, level - 1);

//Used to trigger the level control to refresh.
map.events.invoke('moveend')
```

Comment: I think the reason for the ordinal number being off by one is that in North America, where the sample building is located, floor 1 is the ground floor. I believe the ordinal number is relative to ground level being the 0 index. A similar building in Europe where Ground floor is often called floor 0, may account for this and not have the offset.

Comment: Any idea where the data "FCL13" comes from? I've asked my own SO question in regards to setting facility Ids for tilesets.  The creator tutorial seems to hard code this somewhere. My only guess is it's somewhere in the dwg files.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I haven't touched this in a while, I believe it is auto assigned when the building data is uploaded.

Comment: My other SO question was just answered and yes you are correct. Thank you anyway